# Is 'resetted' a word?

Tags: spelling

[Link 1](https://www.wordplays.com/scrabble-dictionary/resetted)

[Link 2](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/reset)

I entered "resetted" and for the spell check, I searched and got the first link. I thought it is correct because (I thought all words are not included in a spell checker)<sup>1</sup> and after that, I visited the second link.

- Which link is correct?
- Which one should one trust?
- Is reference<sup>1</sup> correct?

[image]

Comment: Did you check a standard reference for verb conjugation like [this one](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-reset.html)?

Comment: @CanadianYankee  Could you send a list of standard reference sites?

Comment: @CanadianYankee  Yes, Link 2 in the question

Answer (score 4):

The simple past of “to reset” is just “reset”, same as the simple present except that it doesn’t become “resets” for the third person singular.

Comment: Did you mean to write _third person singular_?

Comment: @mdewey Yes, thanks.

Comment: So it's an [irregular verb](https://www.englishpage.com/irregularverbs/irregularverbs.html), even though [not all lists](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/irregular_verbs/index.html) include it.